# Find $I_n(a)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^n}, \, a\ne0, \, 0\ne n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity

Find $$I_n(a)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^n}, \, a\ne0, \, 0\ne n \in \mathbb{N}.$$

I have following ideas. We have $I_n(a)=I_n(-a)$.
\begin{align}
\forall \,0\ne n \in \mathbb{N},&\, f(x,a)=\dfrac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n}\, \text{is continuous on}\, D=[0,1]\times(0; \infty)\\
&f^{'}_a(x,a)=\dfrac{-2na}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}\, \text{is continuous on}\, D.
\end{align}

So, $$I^{'}_n(a)=\displaystyle \int \limits_0^1 \dfrac{-2nadx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}=-2naI_{n+1}(a)$$

I just think here.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There's an error: $\:f'_a(x,a)=\dfrac{-2na}{(x^2+a^2)^{n\color{red}{+1}}}$.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark: Find $I_n(a)$

Comment: @Bernard: Ok, I have already edited.

Comment: How to compute the antiderivative has been described many times before on this site. For example, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387914/integrating-a-partial-fraction-with-multiple-quadratic-denominators or https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I_n(a)=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^n}$$
If:
$$u=\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n}\Rightarrow u'=\frac{-2nx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}$$
$$v'=1\Rightarrow v=x$$
so by IBP:
$$I_n(a)=\left[\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^n}\right]_0^1+\int_0^1\frac{2nx^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n(a)=\frac{1}{(1+a^2)^n}+2n\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^n}-\frac{a^2}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}\right)dx$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=\frac{1}{(1+a^2)^n}+2n\left(I_n-a^2I_{n+1}\right)$$
Now rearrange for $I_{n+1}$:
$$2na^2I_{n+1}=\frac{1}{(1+a^2)^n}+(2n-1)I_n$$
And using this multiple times for a given $n$ will get you down to a final integral $I_1$ which is not too bad to work out :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Traditionally, this kind of integral  is computed recursively. The recurrence  relation is obtained  through an integration by parts: set
$$\begin{cases}
u=\dfrac1{(x^2+a^2)^n},\\
\mathrm dv=\mathrm d x,
\end{cases}\quad\text{whence}\quad\begin{cases}\mathrm d u=-\dfrac{2nx\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}},\\
v=x\end{cases}.$$
Integration by parts then yields
$$I_n(a)=\frac x{(x^2+a^2)^n}\biggr\rvert_0^1+2n\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{x^2\,\mathrm dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{n+1}}}_{I_n-a^2I_{n+1}}=\cdots$$