# integration by substitution, using $\;t = \tan \left(\frac 12 x\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{1}{2-\cos x} \, dx$ using the substitution $t=\tan\frac{1}{2}x$

> - $x=2\tan^{-1}t$
> - $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}$
> - $dx=\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}\,dt$
> - $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2-\cos x}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt$

Is this the right idea? If so what do I do next?

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{2-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}}\right) \,\left(\frac{2}{1+t^2}\right)\, dt$

$\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{2}{1+3t^2}\,dt$

$=2\left[\frac{\ln(1+3t^2)}{6t}\right]_0^1$

Comment: Can you express $\cos x$ in terms of $t$ to complete the substitution?

Comment: And also note that you need to attend to the limits of your integral.

Comment: I am not sure how to, no..?

Comment: The reason that the $t=\tan \frac x 2$ substitution (sometimes called the Weierstrass Substitution) is so useful, is that $\sin x = \cfrac {2t}{1+t^2}$ and $\cos x = \cfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ - so it reduces trigonometric integrals to integrals of rational functions. The formulae should remind you of Pythagoras. Your first task is to prove these formulae, and then investigate online, so that you have a strong grasp of what is going on here. This simple substitution is a first introduction to some important mathematical ideas.

Comment: @MarkBennet Which important ideas? I only know the substitution as an isolated trick.

Comment: Well this substitution parametrizes the unit circle. The idea is considerably generalised in the study of algebraic curves in algebraic geometry.

Comment: After substituting, I think you should be at $\int_0^1 \frac{2\,dt}{1+3t^2}$. The substitution $\sqrt{3}t=u$ then gets us to the end.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Use another substitution?!

Comment: Your last integral should be as indicated by André Nicolas, $$\frac{1}{2-\dfrac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}}\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}=\frac{2}{2(1+t^{2})-(1-t^{2})}=\frac{2}{1+3t^{2}}=\frac{2}{1+(\sqrt{3}t)^{2}}$$

Comment: @AméricoTavares can you not just do what I have done?! You end up with a weird decimal when you do what i have done I don't understand why.

Comment: I've just pointed out that the integrand should be $2/(1+3t^2)$ and not $2/(1+2t^2)$ as it was before your last edit. The final integral should be $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{1+3t^{2}}dt=\left. \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{3}\arctan t\sqrt{3}\right\vert _{0}^{1}=\frac{2}{9}\pi \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: A more thorough derivation of this substitution can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks#124227).

Answer (score 3):

If $\;t = \tan\left(\frac 12 x\right)$, i.e., $\,x = 2\tan^{-1}t,\,$ what should $\dfrac 1{2 - \cos x}$ then be?

We need to replace the function (integrand) of $x$ to one expressed as a function of $t$.

What are the new limits for $\,t\,$ if $\;t = \tan\left(\frac 12 x\right)$?

When $x = 0,\;$ $t = \tan\left(\frac 02\right) = 0$. Okay. But, when $x = \pi/2$, the upper limit of integration needs to be $t = \tan\left(\pi/4\right)$

See [Weierstrass Substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution) for why $\;\cos x = \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2},\;$ and in general, for the logic of using "$t$-substitution": $t = \tan \frac x2$.

---

ADDED:

After substituting all of the above, we should have the integrand:

$$\frac{1}{2-\dfrac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}}\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}=\frac{2}{2(1+t^{2})-(1-t‌​^{2})}=\frac{2}{1+3t^{2}}=\frac{2}{1+(\sqrt{3}t)^{2}}$$

So we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{2}{1+(\sqrt{3}t)^{2}}\,dt = 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{3}t)^{2}}\,dt\tag{1}$$

Now, I'm afraid to say, the work isn't done yet. We cannot use $\ln|f(t)|$ where $f(t) =1 + \sqrt{3}t)^{2}$ because we do not have an integrand in the form of $\;\dfrac{f'(t)}{f(t)} \,dx$.

But we're all set up with $(1)$ to use the substitution $$u = \sqrt 3 t.\,\implies du = \sqrt 3 dt \implies dt = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} du$$

Then we have an integrand of the form $$2 \int_0^{\sqrt 3} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 3} \dfrac{1}{1 + u^2}\,du = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt 3}\int_0^{\sqrt 3}  \dfrac{1}{1 + u^2}\,du\tag{2}$$

Now, we [**recall**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_.2B_x2) that $$\int \dfrac {1}{1 + u^2} \,du = \tan^{-1}u + C\tag{$\star$}$$

Can you try and finish it from here? Apply $\star$ to the integral given by $(2)$

---

$(\star)$ See [trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trig_substitution#Integrals_containing_a2_.2B_x2) for integrals involving $a^2 + u^2$, where $a$ is a constant. Our integral is of the same form, with $a = 1$:

$$\int \frac{du}{a^2 + u^2} = \frac 1a\tan^{-1}\left(\frac ua\right)\,+ C$$

Comment: $\int_{0}^1$ ---

Comment: Yes, indeed. You answered before I finished writing...;-)

Comment: So you multiply out $\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2-\cos x}\right)\left(\frac{2}{1+t^2}\right)\,dt$  and then put the new limits in? and then what do you do about the $cosx$?

Comment: @maxmitch - as soon as you change $dx$ to $dt$ in the integral, you need to put in the limits for $t$ instead of the ones for $x$.

Comment: Note that for $t = \tan\left(x/2\right)$, we have $\;\cos x= \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

Comment: Sorry stupid mistake! I don't remember being taught that $cosx=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$....! (not to be confused with factorial ;) )

Comment: is my update correct?

Comment: See updated solution. When I used substitution again, I changed to bounds of integration so they apply to $u$, so no need to "back substitute"

Comment: @amWhy: Very nice and detailed answer! Very slow day for me, and I have been making lots of really silly errors! Guess I have lots on my mind with another talk this week! Hope all is well! Regards

Comment: Thanks, Amzoti! Very slow for me today, as well... :-(

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

When $\tan \dfrac{x}{2}=t$ you have $ \cos x= \dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$

Answer (score 0):

If $x=2\arctan t$ then $\cos x = \cos\left(2\arctan t\right)$.  Use the fact that $\cos(2u)=\cos^2u-\sin^2u$.  So you get
$$
\cos x = \cos^2\left(\arctan t \right) -\sin^2\left(\arctan t \right)
$$

If $\varphi=\arctan t$ then $\dfrac t1=t = \tan\varphi=\dfrac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$, so $\cos\varphi=\dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$.  So $\text{opposite}=t$, $\text{adjacent}=1$, and by the Pythagorean theorem $\text{hypotenuse}=\sqrt{1+t^2}$.

Then $\cos=\dfrac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$ and so
$$
\cos^2(2\arctan t) = \cos^2 (\cdot)-\sin^2(\cdot) = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\right)^2 - \left(\text{something similar}\right)^2 = \cdots\cdots
$$