# How to find the antiderivative of the following function:

Tags: integration

How to calculate the following integral without using wolfram mathematica:
$$
\int\frac{dx}{(x^2-4x+5)^2}
$$

Comment: Set $x-2=t$ and then follow the description here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Answer (score 4):

You can do this without partial fraction decomposition. Note that when completing the square in the denominator, we get:
$$x^2 - 4x + 5 = (x - 2)^2 + 1$$

So you'll want to make use of the substitution $x-2 = \tan \theta \implies dx = \sec^2 \theta$.

Then also note that $\tan^2 \theta + 1 = \sec^2\theta$.

Comment: Partial Fraction Decomposition is not required, right if we use Trigonometric Substitution?

Comment: I've never heard of the function $\sec\theta$.

Comment: it's the secant function, and $\sec \theta = \dfrac 1{\cos \theta}$

Comment: I don't understand how to calculate the integral.

Comment: If the function was $\frac{1}{x^2-4x+5}$ then I can solve it: $\int\frac{d(x-2)}{(x-2)^2+1} = \arctan(x-2)$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Split the fraction $$\frac{1}{(x^2 - 4x + 5)^2}$$ into partial fractions.

Also, use hints from [these notes](http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/winter06/20b/notes/html/node37.html).

Comment: What is a partial fraction?

Comment: When you have a factorable polynomial denominator of the form $p_1(x)p_2(x)...p_n(x)$, where $p_i(x)$ are irreducible factors, you can decompose the rational function as such: $$\frac{1}{p_1(x)p_2(x)...p_n(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{A_k}{p_k(x)}}.$$ Thas is partial fraction decomposition. You should be able to integrate that.

Comment: If you want to avoid the complex log, see the other answer.