# How to solve the integral of $\frac 1{(x^2+1)^2}$

Tags: calculus

I need to evaluate 
$$
\int_0^1 \dfrac 1{(x^2+1)^2}.
$$

I was absent for this lecture and I'm sort of lost on where to go.

I set $x = \tan (\theta)$ and $dx = \sec^2(\theta)\, d\theta$. And this implies that

$$x^2 + 1 = \tan^2(\theta) + 1 = \sec^2(\theta).$$

Now I have the integral of $\dfrac {\sec^2(\theta)}{(\sec^2\theta)^2}\, d\theta.$

I don't think I've done this properly, but if you could explain the process of doing trig substitutions in general, I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Honestly, if I were you, I would evaluate $I(a)=\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{dx}{x^2+a}~,~$ which is trivial, and then I'd express the entire integral in terms of $I'(1)$.

Comment: @Lucian: Normally in a first course on integration, differentiation under the integral sign is not taught.

Comment: Here's yet another way: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks/689932#689932

Comment: I don't think I fully understand these, but thank you for pointing these methods out. Differentiation under the integral sign looks pretty useful and might be something useful for me to teach myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are on the right track, but be careful as you are doing definite integral, you need also to change the lower and upper limit.

Now $x = \tan \theta$. When $x = 0$, $\theta = 0$; when $x = 1$, $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$. So you have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+ x^2)^2} dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{\sec ^2 \theta}{(\sec ^2\theta)^2}d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{1}{\sec ^2\theta }d\theta = \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2\theta d\theta$$

Now use the half angle formula

$$\cos ^2\theta = \frac{1}{2} (1+ \cos(2\theta))$$

to get

$$\int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2\theta d\theta = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\pi/4} \big(1  + \cos (2\theta)\big) d\theta.$$

Can you fill in the remaining steps?

Comment: 1/2 int (1 + Cos2theta) from 0 to pi/4 d theta, equals:

1/2 times x + sin(2theta)/2, evaluate from 0 to pi/4

1/2( pi/4 + 1/2) = (pi + 2)/8

Answer (score 1):

You have almost done! What is $\dfrac{1}{\sec\theta}$? Is that equal to $\cos\theta$? So you need to take a definite integral of $\cos^2\theta$ on that interval. Moreover, I'd like to warn you for taking any substitution for definite integral so fast. Indeed, we should satisfy some important conditions to do any substitution easily. See [Relation to the fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) again.

Comment: I sort of forgot that 1/sec theta is = cos theta. I feel so silly for not recognising such an intuitive thing. Thank you

Comment: (-: :-) $~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 0):

make a change of variable $$x = \tan t, t = \tan^{-1} x \to dt = \frac{dx}{1+x^2}   $$

$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^2} = \int_0^{\pi/4} \frac{dt}{1+ \tan^2 t} = \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos^2 t \,dt = \frac 12\int_0^{\pi/4} 1 + \cos 2t \, dt = \frac 12\left( \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac12\right)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, this was helpful in checking my answer after working it out using some of the hints.