# Find $\int x^ne^xdx$

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int x^ne^xdx$.

I haven't been able to figure this out. Do I just keep repeatedly applying integration by parts?

Comment: Pretty much. ${}$

Comment: This is a duplicate of that question of mine, in fact it's a less general case (take $b=-1$).

Comment: If $n$ is assumed to be a positive integer, as suggested by the question but not made explicit, then the situation is significantly better than the one outlined in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Regarding repeated integration by parts, see also this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks/71195#71195

Answer (score 4):

May I recommend integration by undetermined coefficients, where given some $n$, we know the solution will take the form $P(x)e^x + C$, where $P(x)$ is some polynomial of degree $n$. (It really can't be anything else). So write $P(x)$ as $a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n$, take the derivative, and back out the coefficients.

Or if you want to get practice, use integration by parts. But that's really nasty.

Comment: I read for a brief moment "underdefined coefficients" :P

Answer (score 3):

Finding an explicit formula for the antiderivative will involve the incomplete Gamma function.

What you could do (and what is usually standard) is get a recurrence relation.

Let $$I_n = \int x^n e^x dx, \ n\in \mathbb{N}\cup{0}$$ Integration by parts yields

$$I_n = x^n e^x -n \int x^{n-1} e^x dx = x^n e^x - n I_{n-1}.$$

The first term in this recurrence relation is $$I_0 = e^x.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach for definite integrals:

Let $I(t) = \int_a^b e^{tx} dx = {1 \over t} (e^{tb}-e^{ta})$.

Then
$I^{(n)}(1) = \int_a^b x^n e^{x} dx$.

Comment: This is a very efficient approach and the one that I would use.  +1   Happy holidays! - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV: Happy holidays to you too!

Answer (score 1):

Notice, integrating by parts as follows  $$\int x^ne^x\ dx$$
$$=x^n\int e^x\ dx-\int nx^{n-1}e^x\ dx$$
$$=x^ne^x-nx^{n-1}e^x+n\int (n-1)x^{n-2}e^x\ dx$$
$$=x^ne^x-nx^{n-1}e^x+n(n-1)x^{n-2}e^x-n(n-1)\int (n-2)x^{n-3}e^x\ dx$$
$$................$$
$=\left(x^n-nx^{n-1}+n(n-1)x^{n-2}-n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}+\ldots +(-1)^{n+1}n!\right)e^x+C$

$\forall \ \ n\in N$