# Where to show my work on integrals?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, research

I am not sure if Mathematics Stack Exchange allows this kind of questions. But I do think there are some who can guide me through this.

I am working on Indefinite Integrals for quite a long time and I have developed some of my own methods to evaluate long integrals like $\tan^nx$, $\sec^nx$ and $\cot^nx.$ I know we have reduction formulas for these integrals, but personally I don't find it useful for two obvious reasons:

1.It's hard to keep in mind.

2.It takes quite a long time, specially if you are dealing with $\tan^{20}x$ or something like that.

Besides this I have my own methods for integrals like $\tan x$,$\sec x$,$\cot x$,$\csc x$ and some of my own results on integrals.

Are they worth sending to some research society? Where can I do the same?

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by Joanpemo,I would like to show my one of my works. But since I don't know if these results have been derived in the past, I am posting one of my questions.I will show my work after seeing the answers.

$1. \int \tan^{13}x dx$

Comment: I think it is hard somebody will tell you something without first seeing your results, so either post them here and everybody will know they're yours, or else show them to somebody in your school.

Comment: If you can post here then beginners like me can learn !

Comment: @ArchisWelankar me just 428, I consider myself a beginner only.

Comment: Post it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks :-)

Comment: If you fear that somebody might steal your results, which is unlikely on such a theme and on a site like this one, you can begin by posting one of your methods e.g. at the address indicated by @Hans Lundmark

Comment: @JeanMarie No, i don't fear that they can be stolen on a site like this. I will post one of them here.

Comment: @JeanMarie My results are not so astonishing, Indeed I have my own ways of looking at  integrals which have been evaluated before and a method to get rid of reduction formulas. That's why i am not sure if they are even worth noticing.