# How to integrate the following function???

Tags: calculus

$\int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}$.
I tried to use partial method  were $u\:=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}$ and dv = dx but got no result.

Comment: Hint: Substitute $x = a \tan(\theta)$.

Comment: It's a trigonometric substitution and I'm surprised they haven't taught you that in baby calculus. That's a standard calculation method, it's nothing weird or exotic. Sigh-what are they teaching these kids now?

Comment: Here's another way: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $x=a \tan{t}.$ Then $dx=\frac{a\,dt}{\cos^2{t}}, $ and
$$\int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+a^2\right)^3}=\int \frac{a\,dt}{\cos^2{t}\cdot a^6 \left(1+ \tan^2{t}\right)^3} = \frac{1}{a^5}\int \frac{\cos^6{t}\,dt}{\cos^2{t}}=\frac{1}{a^5}\int {\cos^4{t}\,dt}.$$

Comment: Yup. And now the final integral is straightforward if not easy.