# How to calculate $\int \frac{dx}{(a^2 + x^2)^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to use a trig substitution but I'm stuck. Here's what I did so far:

$$\int \frac{dx}{(a^2 + x^2)^2}$$

Let $x = a\sin \theta, dx = a\cos \theta d\theta$

$$\int \frac{a cos\theta d\theta}{(a^2 + a^2 sin^2 \theta)^2} = \int \frac{a\cos \theta d\theta}{(a^2(1+sin^2\theta))^2} $$

$$\int \frac{a\cos \theta d\theta}{(a^2 \cos^2\theta)^2} =\int \frac{d\theta}{a^3cos^3\theta}  $$

I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: The integral of $\sec^3\theta$ is doable, but messy.  It's often an example in Calculus texts.

Comment: set $$x=a\tan(t)$$

Comment: You seem to have claimed that $1+\sin^2\theta=\cos^2\theta$, which is incorrect.  Instead, use $1+\tan^2\theta=\sec^2\theta$.

Comment: @Randall Don't you mean $sec^2 \theta$ ?

Comment: @Trey no, I meant the cube (as in the last line of your problem), as it is a famously long and annoying derivation.  But, as the other posters have pointed out, this is no longer relevant.

Comment: Umm... $\cos^2(\theta)=1\color{#C00}{-}\sin^2(\theta)$

Comment: Indeed, $x\neq a\sin \theta$.  The form $a^2 + x^2$ corresponds to $x = a\tan x$.  And so $$(a^2 + x^2) = (a^2 + a^2\tan^2 x) = a^2(1 +\tan^2 x) = a^2( \sec^2 x)$$   Please see [the "trig substitution" Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) for a better grasp of what trig function to use for substitution, and in which cases.

Comment: Another method is to let $x=at$ and proceed as explained here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $x=a\tan(u)$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^2}
&=\frac1{a^3}\int\frac{\sec^2(u)\,\mathrm{d}u}{\sec^4(u)}\\
&=\frac1{a^3}\int\cos^2(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac1{2a^3}\int(1+\cos(2u))\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac1{2a^3}(u+\sin(u)\cos(u))+C\\
&=\frac1{2a^3}\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac xa\right)+\frac{ax}{a^2+x^2}\right)+C\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: isn't $\int cos (2u) = \frac{sin 2u}{2}$ ? Why did you write $sin(u)cos(u)$?

Comment: @Trey: Are they not the same thing?

Answer (score 2):

For any $A>0$ we have 
$$ \int\frac{dx}{A+x^2}=C+\frac{1}{\sqrt{A}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}}$$
hence by differentiating both sides with respect to $A$ we get
$$ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+A)^2} = D+\frac{x}{2A(x^2+A)}+\frac{1}{2A\sqrt{A}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{A}} $$
and now we just have to evaluate both sides at $A=a^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use that
$$
\int\frac{\text{d}x}{a^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{a}\text{arctan}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)+K
$$
And then integrating by parts gives you

$$
\int\frac{\text{d}x}{a^2+x^2}=\left[\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}\right]+\int \frac{2x^2}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^2}\text{d}x$$
$$=\left[\frac{x}{a^2+x^2}\right]+2\int \frac{\text{d}x}{a^2+x^2}-2a^2\int \frac{\text{d}x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^2}
$$
Then
$$
2a^3\int \frac{\text{d}x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^2}=\left[\frac{ax}{a^2+x^2}\right]+\text{arctan}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)
$$
You finally obtain

> $$
> \int \frac{\text{d}x}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2a^3}\left(\frac{ax}{a^2+x^2}+\text{arctan}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)+C
> $$

Answer (score 1):

observe that $$a^2+a^2\tan^2(t)=a^2(1+\tan^2(t))=\frac{a^2}{\cot^2(t)}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\dfrac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)+C$$
then
$$\dfrac{d}{da}\int\dfrac{dx}{a^2+x^2}=\dfrac{d}{da}\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)+C\right)$$
and
$$\int\dfrac{-2adx}{(a^2+x^2)^2}=\dfrac{1}{2a^3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{a}\right)-\dfrac{x}{2a^2(a^2+x^2)}$$

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a "general" way.

Denoting
$$
I_k=\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^k},
$$
one has (for $k>1$)
$$
\begin{align}
I_k&=\frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{(x^2+a^2)-x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^k}\ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2} I_{k-1}-\frac{1}{a^2}\int\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^k}\ dx\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2} I_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2a^2(k-1)}\int x\ d\left(\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{k-1}}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{a^2} I_{k-1}+\frac{1}{2a^2(k-1)}\left[\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{k-1}}-I_{k-1}\right],
\end{align}
$$
which gives 
$$
I_k=\frac{x}{2a^2(k-1)(x^2+a^2)^{k-1}}+\frac{2k-3}{2a^2(k-1)}I_{k-1}.
$$
Now you can get $I_2$ by observing that
$$
I_1=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{x}{a}+C.
$$

---

<sup>**Notes**: The recursive relation above allows one to calculate $I_k$ for any positive integer $k$ in principle, which can be used to calculate any indefinite integral of [rational functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function).</sup>