# Integration methodologies other than integration by parts/substitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Are there any integration methodologies to find **antiderivatives** of functions, other than integration by parts/substitution?

General methods are preferred, but some methods that can be applied to specific functions are welcomed if there aren't.

Too broad...? :)

Maybe it can be duplicate, so I accept definite integral methods.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Calculus_Cheat_Sheet_Integrals.pdf)?

Comment: @GoodDeeds Thanks! And I think I have found the same thing on google 1h ago :) (calculus-cheat-sheets-integrals_reduced.pdf) and I think I've learned them all before.

Comment: Everything builds on those two methods, since they are just the Leibniz product rule and the chain rule used backwards. But this might be of interest anyway: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks

Comment: @HansLundmark Thanks! I'll check that.

Comment: Cannot forget to mention [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) also.