# Using variation of parameters to solve $y''-25y=x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I keep trying to solve this but I end up needing to do integration by parts like 3 or 4 times. My only question is, is that going to be the only way to do this? If so it will literally take me hours. I don't need a solution, just a confirmation that if the requirement is to use variation of parameters, then will I need to take integrals that need to be done by IBP?

Thank you and sorry if this is not a good question.

Comment: See method of undetermined coefficients? I suppose you are doing derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$... It makes sense that if $y$ is just degree $1$ polynomial of $x$, $y''$ is nothing.

Comment: You don't get anything worse than $\int x e^{\pm 5x} dx$, do you? Those shouldn't take you hours to do, it can be done in *seconds*! See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks/71195#71195

Answer (score 3):

Hint.

This is a linear DE so it's solution can be written as

$$
y = y_h + y_p\\
y''_h-25y_h=0\\
y''_p-25y_p=x
$$

The solution for $y_h = c_1 e^{5x}+c_2 e^{-5x}$.

Assuming now

$$
y_p = c_1(x)e^{5x}+c_2(x)e^{-5x}
$$

substituting into the complete DE we have

$$
e^{5 x} \left(C_1'(x)+10 C_1(x)\right)+e^{-5 x} \left(C_2'(x)-10 C_2(x)\right)-x = 0
$$

with $C_1(x) = c_1'(x), C_2(x) = c_2'(x)$

Now choosing and solving

$$
C_1'(x)+10 C_1(x)=0\\
e^{-5 x} \left(C_2'(x)-10 C_2(x)\right)-x = 0
$$

we have

$$
C_1(x) = K_1e^{-10x} = c_1'(x)\\
C_2'(x)-10 C_2(x)=x e^{5x}
$$

This last equation in $C_2(x)$ can be solved applying again the variation of constants method etc.

NOTE

$$
c_1'(x) = K_1 e^{-10x}\\
c_2'(x) = K_2e^{10x}-\left(\frac x5+\frac{1}{25}\right)e^{5x}
$$

etc.