# What are some of your favourite integration techniques that are rare or unusual

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

Hello could any one tell me some unusual or advanced integration techniques, I am already familiar with the standard ones like u-substitution, integration by parts, trig substitution, partial fractions, Feynman technique (differentiation under the integral), integrating the inverse, Laplace transforms In the integral and matrix inversion so I was wondering if anyone knew some rare ones (definite or indefinite)

Please do not answer with any already listed
Otherwise Any help is appreciated 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Glasser's Master Theorem and Ramanujan's Master Theorem.

Comment: I found the technique for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$ by squaring and using polar coordinates very elegant but I think it is specific to this particular integral. This also gives you an easy way to get the surface of the $n$ dimensional sphere.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks

Answer (score 3):

Two little known (perhaps?) methods for finding indefinite integrals are:

1. *The Rules of Bioche* - Are rules used to guide one towards the most effective trigonometric substitution to use in integrals of the form
   $$\int f(\sin x, \cos x) \, dx,$$
   where $f$ is a rational function of sine and cosine. For more details, see [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0020739X.2021.1912841) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).
2. *Ostrogradsky's Method* - Is a method that finds the rational part of
   $$\int \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \, dx,$$
   without having to find a factorisation for $Q$ and without having to decompose the integrand into partial fractions. Here $P$ and $Q$ are polynomials such that $\deg P < \deg Q$. For more details, see [here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=Kck-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA149&lpg=PA149&dq=%22Ostrogradsky%27s%20method%22&source=bl&ots=P2TXZg2629&sig=ACfU3U0NcCmolANXQucb4FzwPtZ6TL5Vjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJqeju76TjAhWKf7wKHTcFAWcQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Ostrogradsky%27s%20method%22&f=false).