# Calculating an infinite integral by Residue theorem

Tags: improper-integrals, special-functions, residue-calculus

As far as I can tell, the following infinite integral holds,
$$
I(m,n) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^n)^m} dx = \frac{\Gamma(1+1/n)\Gamma(m-1/n)}{\Gamma(m)}.
$$
Here, $m \geq1, n \geq 2$ are integers. $\Gamma(x)$ is the well-known Gamma function.

When $m = 1$, it is shown in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247866/show-that-int-0-infty-frac11xn-dx-frac-pi-n-sin-pi-n-wh). Some other cases can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558540/integrate-int-0-infty-frac11x2n-dx?r=SearchResults).

My Questions are that: (1) How can we proof the above integral identity nicely? (2) Is there a way to calculate the above integral by **Residue theorem**?

Comment: look for google 'ramanujan master theorem' :D

Comment: The integral is immediately converted into a value of the Beta function by the substitution $\frac{1}{1+x^n}=u$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Firts of all, using the Gaussian hypergeometric function, the antiderivative is
$$I(m,n) = \int \frac{dx}{(1+x^n)^m}  = x\, \, _2F_1\left(m,\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};-x^n\right)$$
$$J(m,n) = \int_0^t \frac{dx}{(1+x^n)^m}  =t \,\, _2F_1\left(m,\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};-t^n\right)$$
$$K(m,n) = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{(1+x^n)^m}  =\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) \Gamma \left(m-\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma
   (m)}$$

If you want to use residues, think about [Barnes integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes_integral).

Answer (score 0):

We may use the generalized Newton's binomial and the Ramanujan Master Theorem (RMT).

The binomial theorem states the following (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$$\frac{1}{(1+y)^m}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{m+k-1}{k}(-x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(m+k-1)!}{(m-1)!}\frac{(-x)^k}{k!}$$

For convenience we may define $\phi(k)=\frac{(m+k-1)!}{(m-1)!}$.

Let's recall the RMT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem), which states that if a complex-valued function $f(x)$ has an expansion of the form
$ f(x)=\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {\,\varphi (k)\,}{k!}}(-x)^{k}$ then

$$\int _{0}^{\infty }x^{s-1}f(x)\,dx=\Gamma (s)\,\varphi (-s)$$

Now we may observe that the initial integral may be seen as a Mellin transform; applying it to the case at hand we obtain the following

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{(1+x^n)^m}=\frac{1}{n}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{y^{\tfrac{1}{n} -1}dy}{(1+y)^m}=\frac{1}{n}\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\frac{(m-1-\tfrac{1}{n})!}{(m-1)!}
$$
the change of variable we made was $y=x^n$.

Solving further, we get the following
$$I=\frac{\Gamma\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)\Gamma\left(m-\tfrac{1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma\left(m\right)}$$