# How to evaluate $\int \frac1{(x^2+a^2)^{m}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

The integral $$\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^m}dx$$ can be expressed by a recursive formula of $$\frac{1}{2a^2(m-1)}\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} + \frac{2m-3}{2a^2(m-1)}\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}}$$ I do not understand how integration by part leads to this result. Specifically, since $$\int u dv = uv - \int v du$$ I want to know what is $u$, $du$, $v$, $dv$.

Comment: Hint: Put $x = a\tan(\theta)$ this will simplify your integral to $\int a^{1-2m} \sec^{2-2m} (\theta)\ d\theta$. After this try integration by parts.

Comment: This integral can be represented via hypergeometric function

Comment: @MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad I think you should read body of the post again.

Comment: @Utkarsh my bad...i thought the question asked to solve the integral

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Comment: $\int \frac{1}{\left(a^2+x^2\right)^m} \, dx =  x \left(a^2+x^2\right)^{-m} \left(\frac{x^2}{a^2}+1\right)^m \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},m;\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{a^2}\right) + C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$J = \int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^m} = \dfrac1{a^2}\int\dfrac{(a^2+x^2)-x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^m}dx$$
and hence
$$J = \dfrac1{a^2}\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} - \dfrac1{a^2}\int\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^m}dx$$
which gives
$$J = \dfrac1{a^2}\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} + \dfrac{1}{2a^2(m-1)}\int x\,d\, \dfrac1{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}}$$
Integrating by parts, we get
$$J = \dfrac1{a^2}\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} + \dfrac{1}{2a^2(m-1)} \dfrac {x}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} - \dfrac{1}{2a^2(m-1)}\int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}}$$
and hence
$$J = \dfrac{1}{2a^2(m-1)} \dfrac {x}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} + \dfrac{2m-3}{2a^2(m-1)}\int \dfrac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Integrate by parts as follows

\begin{align}
&\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^m}dx\\
= &\int \frac1{2a^2(m-1)x^{2m-3}}\ d\left[\bigg(\frac{x^2}{x^2+a^2} \bigg)^{m-1}\right]\\
=&\  \frac{1}{2a^2(m-1)}\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}} + \frac{2m-3}{2a^2(m-1)}\int\frac{1}{(x^2+a^2)^{m-1}}dx
\end{align}
Thus
$$u= \frac1{2a^2(m-1)x^{2m-3}},\>\>\>\>\>
v= \left(\frac{x^2}{x^2+a^2} \right)^{m-1} $$