# Calculating the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^3}dx$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

The above integral appeared while trying to calculate the Fisher-information of a Cauchy-distributed sample in my statistics homework. I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha, which gives the answer $\frac \pi 8$, and it's also able to find the indefinite integral, but I'm unable to infer what method it used.

So far, I have tried substituting a couple things, such as $(1 + x^2)$, $x^2$, or $(1 + x^2)^3$, but nothing seems to have worked. I also tried integrating by parts, integrating the $x^2$ on the top and differentiating the denominator, but this also doesn't work out. I also tried splitting the integral by writing the $x^2$ in the nominator as $(1 + x^2) - 1$, but this isn't fruitful either.

I am of course aware that I'm supposed to get an $\arctan$ somewhere in there, but I have no idea how to sneak it into the expression.

I'm sure someone among the userbase here has faced a similar integral before, can I maybe get a hint on how to proceed? What is the trick here?

Comment: Residues is the quickest way to go. Otherwise to use FTC just partial fractions and integrate. It should be trivial either way

Comment: Your idea with $(1+x^2)-1$ works if you combine it with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/70974/lesser-known-integration-tricks/689932#689932).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute it using residues. The function$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb C\setminus\{\pm i\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\dfrac{z^2}{(z^2+1)^3}\end{array}$$is a rational function whose numerator has degree $2$ and whose denominator has degree $6$; in particular, $\lim_{z\to\infty}zf(z)=0$. Furthermore, it has one and only one singularity in the upper half-plane, located at $i$. So\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx&=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=i}f(z)\\&=2\pi i\times\left(\frac{-i}{16}\right)\\&=\frac\pi8.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks so much! It completely slipped my mind that I can use complex methods to evaluate real integrals. That said though, this doesn't explain how Wolfram Alpha finds an antiderivative, since this method only gives the definite integral on the entire real line.

Comment: Using the fact that$$(\forall x\in\Bbb R):\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}=\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}-\frac{1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^3}.$$Now, use the fact that$$\int\frac1{(x^2+1)^2}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x}{x^2+1}+\arctan (x)\right)$$and that$$\int\frac1{(x^2+1)^3}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{8} \left(\frac{3x^3+5x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}+3 \arctan(x)\right).$$

Comment: I was wondering, can't this *definite* integral be solved with the standard integration technique known in highschool?

Comment: @lonestudent What is “the standard integration technique known in highschool”?

Comment: I mean,  first finding the indefinite integral, then calculating the definite integral.

Comment: @lonestudent Sure. See my previous comment to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

My answer using elementary techniques:

$$I=\int\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\mathrm dx$$
Substitute $t=\arctan(x)$ hence $x = \tan(t)$ and $dt = \frac{dx}{1+x^2} $, giving
$$I=\int\frac{\tan^2(t)}{(1+\tan^2(t))^2}\mathrm dt$$
Since $\sec^2(t)=1+\tan^2(t)$:
$$I=\int\frac{\tan^2(t)}{\sec^4(t)}\mathrm dt$$
$$I=\int\frac{\sin^2(t)}{\cos^2(t)}{\cos^4(t)}\mathrm dt$$
$$I=\int\sin^2(t)\cos^2(t)\mathrm dt$$
$$I=\int\sin^2(t)(1-\sin^2(t)\mathrm dt$$
$$I=\int\sin^2(t)dt-\int\sin^4(t)\mathrm dt$$

The rest of it is standard

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Ok @JoséCarlosSantos I will do so... can you let it stay till then?

Comment: It seems likely that it will deleted.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have done the conversion

Answer (score 4):

Because the integrand is even, your integral can be written as $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (...)=2\int_0^\infty (...)$. With this in mind consider the general integral
$$F(p,q)=2\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{p}}{(1+x^2)^q}\mathrm dx$$
Substitute $t=x^2$, giving
$$F(p,q)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}{(1+t)^q}\mathrm dt$$
Recall the following [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Other_identities_and_formulas) of the Beta function:
$$\mathrm B(u,v)=\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{u-1}}{(1+t)^{u+v}}\mathrm dt$$

From which we conclude
$$F(p,q)=\mathrm B\left(\frac{p+1}{2}~,~q-\frac{p+1}{2}\right)$$

Hence, your integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\mathrm dx=2\int_{0}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3}\mathrm dx \\ =F(2,3) \\ =\mathrm B\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right) \\ =\frac{\Gamma(3/2)\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(3/2+3/2)} \\ =\frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)\right)^2}{\Gamma(3)} \\ =\boxed{\frac{\pi}{8}}$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $I_n=\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)^n}.$

$$I_n=\frac x{(x^2+1)^n}+2n\int\frac{x^2dx}{(x^2+1)^{n+1}}=\frac x{(x^2+1)^n}+2n(I_n-I_{n+1}).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3} \, dx \\
&= 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^3} \, dx \tag1 \\
&= 4 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}}{\left(1+\frac{(1-y)^2}{(1+y)^2}\right)^3(1+y)^2} \, dy \tag2\\
&= \frac12 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{(1-y^2)^2}{(1+y^2)^3} \, dy \\
&= \int_0^1 \frac{(1-y^2)^2}{(1+y^2)^3} \, dy \tag1 \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+2) (n+1) \int_0^1 (1-y^2)^2 y^{2n} \, dy \tag3 \\
&= \frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+2)(n+1) \left(\frac1{2n+1} - \frac2{2n+3} + \frac1{2n+5}\right) \\
&= \frac38 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} + \frac14 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+3} + \frac38 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+5} \tag4 \\
&= \left\{\frac38 \sum_{n=0}^\infty - \frac14 \sum_{n=1}^\infty + \frac38 \sum_{n=2}^\infty\right\} \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} \tag5 \\
&= \frac38 \arctan(1) - \frac14 \left(\arctan(1) - 1\right) + \frac38 \left(\arctan(1) - 1 + \frac13\right) = \boxed{\frac\pi8} \tag6
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : symmetry
- $(2)$ : substitute $x=\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}$
- $(3)$ : exploit the Maclaurin series of $\dfrac1{1-y}$
- $(4)$ : partial fractions
- $(5)$ : shift indices on the latter sums
- $(6)$ : recall the Maclaurin series for $\arctan$