# Solve of $\int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+9\right)^2}$ with Partial Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

$$   \int \frac{dx}{\left(x^2+9\right)^2}$$

How would you solve this with partial integration (without trigonometry)?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689932/1242

Comment: Do you mean "partial fractions?"

Comment: @FrançoisMortier I tried something like this but I don't know what to do next ![image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1173011583899807845/1223666685308043304/IMG_20240330_191348.jpg?ex=661aaf68&is=66083a68&hm=c7b5bb879cfca50b0a8f6fcee0e24e772a4b8992272be7d0aa7548d83413dc5f&)

Comment: @HansLundmark thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int 1.\frac{1}{x^2+9}dx=x.\frac{1}{x^2+9}-\int x\left(-\frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2}\right)(2x)dx$$$$=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+2\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)^2}dx$$

$$I=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+2\int \frac{x^2+9-9}{(x^2+9)^2}dx=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+2\int \frac{1}{(x^2+9)}dx-18\int \frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2}dx$$$$I=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+2I-18\int \frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2}dx$$

$$18\int \frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2}dx=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+I=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+\frac{1}{3}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{3}+C$$

$$\int \frac{1}{(x^2+9)^2}dx=\frac{x}{x^2+9}+I=\frac{x}{18(x^2+9)}+\frac{1}{54}\tan^{-1}\frac{x}{3}+C$$

Comment: I think you forgot to multiply by 18 in last line

Comment: @Nil Does this answer your question