# Odd order moments of a symmetrical distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, symmetry

Is it true that for every symmetrical distribution all odd-order moments are equal to zero?

If yes, how would I be able to prove such a thing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm going to assume you mean (1) symmetric about $0$, and (2) distributions for which the odd-order moments actually exist.  Under these assumptions, yes.

In the continuous case, the $n$th moment for a distribution with pdf $f(x)$ exists and is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f(x) \,dx,$$
exactly when the integral converges.  So, what does it mean for the integral to converge?

Remember that we define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f(x) \,dx$ to be $$ \int_{-\infty}^0 x^n f(x) \, dx + \int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) \, dx.$$  (Well, we could choose some point other than $0$ to split the integral, but $0$ works fine.)  Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f(x) \,dx$ is equivalent to the convergence of both of these integrals.  Existence of the $n$th odd-order moment, then, is equivalent to $\int_{-\infty}^0 x^n f(x) \, dx$ and $\int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) \, dx$ both being finite.

Suppose $\int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) \, dx = A$.  If we let $u = -x$, then $$\int_{-\infty}^0 x^n f(x) \, dx = \int_{\infty}^0 (-u)^n f(-u) \, (-du) = (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} u^n f(-u) \, du = - \int_0^{\infty} u^n f(u) \, du  = -A,$$
where the first step is legitimate because the integral converges and the third step follows because $n$ is odd and $f$ is symmetric about the origin.

Thus, if the $n$th odd-order moment exists, it is equal to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n f(x) \,dx = -A + A = 0.$

The discrete case for $n$ odd is analogous.

Comment: The Wikipedia article referenced restricts itself to integrals over finite intervals $(-A, A)$.  So please considering editing your answer a little to make it more clear that the $n$-th order moment, $n$ odd, exists exactly when  $\int_0^{\infty} x^n f(x) dx$, $n$ odd, has finite value (or converges); and if the moment exists, it has value $0$.

Comment: @Dilip: I can certainly make my answer more precise on that count.

Comment: And what about the neither-absolutely-continuous-neither-discrete case?

Comment: @Didier: I skipped that, didn't I?  I suppose to handle all cases the answer would need to be rewritten in measure-theoretic terms.  My rustiness with the measure-theory approach to probability, though, makes me concerned that I would make too many mistakes were I to try to revise my answer along those lines.  So I think I'll leave my answer as is and acknowledge (via this comment) that I've skipped the case you mention.

Comment: @Mike Spivey: thanks for your answer:) if it's not symmmetric around 0, if e.g. i want to consider the odd-order central moments around a mean value m, with p(i) being a function symmetric around m=125 for i 0-256 (discrete case). does it still hold that these odd-order central moments are all equal to zero?

Comment: @nikos: No.  For instance, in your example $E[X^1] = m = 125$, not $0$.  The higher-order odd moments will be more complicated, but in general they will not be equal to $0$ (or $m$, either, I believe).

Comment: @Mike Spivey: I see...and if i have the following specific problem: let i be a discrete random variable and p(i), i=0,1,...,255 the corresponding histogram and it is given that: for i=0 to 20 the height of the histogram is $C/2$, for i=21 to 234 the height is $C$ and for i=235 to 255 the height is $C/2$. In that occasion is it true that all odd-order moments around the mean value m are all equal to zero. And if yes how can i prove it?

Comment: @nikos: Yes; all odd-order moments around the mean value $m$ will be $0$.  To prove it, do a variable transformation.  If $X$ is your random variable, let $Y = X-m$.  Then $Y$ is symmetric about $0$.  Then, for $n$ odd, $E[(X-m)^n] = E[Y^n] = 0$, by the argument in my answer above.  (And my apologies for misunderstanding your first comment; you did say "central moment," and I missed it.)

Comment: that was superb!

Answer (score 17):

I think it's easier than arguments about integrals and sums.  Saying a random variable $X$ has a symmetric distribution means that $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution.  This means that for any function $f$, if $E[f(X)]$ exists then so does $E[f(-X)]$ and they are equal.  So take $f(x) = x^n$ with $n$ odd.  If $X$ has an $n$th moment, then $E[X^n]$ exists and so $$E[X^n] = E[(-X)^n] = E[(-1)^n X^n] = E[-(X^n)] = -E[X^n]$$ which means $E[X^n] = 0$.

Comment: What does "If $X$ has a $n$th moment, then $E[X^n]$ exists" mean?  I was taught that the $n$th moment of $X$ was _defined_ as the value of $E[X^n]$ if $E[X^n]$ exists, and was undefined otherwise.  The reason I requested @MikeSpivey to revise his answer was to confront this notion of existence of $E[X^n]$, which is obvious to those well-versed in the measure-theoretic approach to probability, but is confusing to beginning students as the OP nikos might well be.  See also [the discussion here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/64651/15941).

Comment: @Nate Eldredge : Your solution is nice. But how to prove it for $E[X]\neq0$. Since distributions of $X$ and $-X$ are equal only for zero-mean distribution.

Comment: @kaka: the question is about symmetric distributions, so we necessarily have  $E[X]=0$ if it exists. (Take $n=1$ in my answer!)

Comment: @ Nate Eldredge: It is not necessary to have $E[X]=0$ for a symmetric distribution.

Comment: @kaka: we must not be using the same definition of "symmetric distribution". Mine is "X and -X are identically distributed". What is yours?