# distribution of continuous symmetric X for which $E\left(X^{2k}\right)=b^k.k!$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

I have a continuous symmetric random variable $X$ for which $E\left(X^{2k}\right)=b^k.k!$. Since it's symmetric, [all of its odd order moments are zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72451/odd-order-moments-of-a-symmetrical-distribution). And in my case, $b=2/n$ where $n$ is a large integer (if it's needed). Does $X$ have a well-known distribution?
What's the distribution of $X$?

Comment: For a centered Laplace distribution you have $E[X^k]=k!b^k$ for all $k$ even

Comment: @Snoop This is correct. Thanks, but it's not my answer. Since I'm looking for an X such that $E(X^k)=b^{\frac{k}{2}}(k/2)!$ for all $k$ even

Comment: of course - that's just a suggestion for a possible direction

Comment: You might look for a distribution with the same moment generating function which is $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{b} t e^{\frac{b t^2}{4}} \text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{b} t}{2}\right)+1$.  This, of course, simplifies for $b=4 but I don't know the name of such a distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Snoop put you on the right path.  Consider

$$Y=\text{sgn}(X)\sqrt{|X|}$$

where $X\sim \text{Laplace}(0,b)$.

I am too lazy to write down the steps so I'll use *Mathematica*:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[Sign[x] Sqrt[Abs[x]], x \[Distributed] LaplaceDistribution[0, b]]

FullSimplify[Moment[dist, 2 k], k ∈ PositiveIntegers]
(* b^k k! *)

FullSimplify[Moment[dist, 2 k - 1], k ∈ PositiveIntegers]
(* 0 *)
```